# Why Mathematica does not interpret this LaTeX code correctly

Tags: output-formatting, latex

```
ToExpression["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", 
TeXForm]
```

It outputs 0 instead of the partial derivative:
$$ \frac{\partial ^{n} f}{\partial x^{n}} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `D[f, {x, n}]` evaluates to `0`. *Mathematica* does not find `x` in the `expression` `f` so it assumes that `f` does not depend on `x`.

The result of the following might be closer to you goal:

```
ToExpression["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f(x)}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", TeXForm]
```

> Derivative[n][f][x]

Comment: Can output to a standform format like `ToString`?

Comment: I do not get what you try to say. Please, use full sentences.

Comment: Can we output the result of texform as a string like `ToString["\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \
\(n\)]f\), \(\[PartialD]\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(n\)]\),\n\
MultilineFunction->None]\)", StandardForm]`.

Comment: What about `ToString[
 ToExpression["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f(x)}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", 
  TeXForm],
 InputForm
 ]`?

Comment: Can you customize a function `ToLaTeXString["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f(x)}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", TeXForm]` to achieve output like `\[PartialD]^nf/\[PartialD]x^n`.

Comment: `ToLaTeXString` is not a built-in function. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: I apologize to you for my flawed English,and I just want a latex language like \$... \$to output a string like `"\!\(\*RowBox[{\"\\\"\\\\!\\\\(\\\\*FractionBox[\\\\(\\\\*SuperscriptBox[\\\\(\[PartialD]\\\\),  \\\\(n\\\\)]f\\\\), \\\\(\[PartialD]\\\\*SuperscriptBox[\\\\(x\\\\), \\\\(n\\\\)]\\\\),\\\\n MultilineFunction->None]\\\\)\\\"\"}]\)"` in MMA.

Comment: So you want `TraditionalForm` so that it would output as you request in your question?

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is to use the 3-arg version of [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) to prevent evaluation:

```
ToExpression["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

> D[f,{x,n}]

You can use [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) to format the output as desired:

```
TraditionalForm[%]
```

[image: [PartialD]^nf/[PartialD]x^n]

If you really want a string, you can use [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString):

```
ToString[
    ToExpression["$ \\frac{\\partial ^{n} f}{\\partial x^{n}} $ ", TeXForm, HoldForm],
    TraditionalForm
]
```

> ```
> "\!\(\*FormBox[TagBox[FractionBox[
> RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[\"\[PartialD]\", \"n\"], \"f\"}], 
> RowBox[{\"\[PartialD]\", SuperscriptBox[\"x\", \"n\"]}],\n\
> MultilineFunction->None],
> HoldForm],
> TraditionalForm]\)"
> ```

Comment: Your answer is excellent.Thank you very much.